# Covariant derivative as a next step to lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

I have seen in [Thinking of Lie derivative for the first time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481628/thinking-of-lie-derivative-for-the-first-time) that one way to think of differentiating a vector field with respect to another vector field is the Lie derivative $L_XY$.

Now, given vector fields $X$ and $Y$ there is another notion of differentiation called the covariant differentiation $\nabla_XY$. What does this do which lie derivative could not do.

Please try to give broad picture than some calculations. Any references are most welcome.

EDIT : The question which John Ma linked does not really answer this question. That question is useful for some one who already know what is lie/covariant/exterior derivative and says how do you relate these. But, what I am asking is some thing else and I do not really know what is covariant derivative and I want to think of covariant derivative in lines of [Thinking of Lie derivative for the first time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481628/thinking-of-lie-derivative-for-the-first-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exterior Derivative vs. Covariant Derivative vs. Lie Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209241/exterior-derivative-vs-covariant-derivative-vs-lie-derivative)

Comment: @JohnMa I have edied my question.